# How to retrieve specific columns in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Can I make my EF objects retrieve only specific columns in the sql executed?

If I have a column that contains a large amount of data that really slows down the query, how can I have my objects exclude that column from the sql generated?

If my table has Id(int), Name(int), Data(blob), how can I make my query be

```
select Id, Name from TableName
```

instead of

```
select Id, Name, Data from TableName
```

From the suggestion below, my method is

```
 public List<T> GetBy<T>(DbContext context,Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp, Expression<Func<T,T>> columns) where T : class
    {

        return dbContext.Set<T>().Where(exp).Select<T,T>(columns).ToList();
    }
```

And I'm calling it like so

```
List<CampaignWorkType> list = GetBy<CampaignWorkType>(dbContext, c => c.Active == true, n => new { n.Id, n.Name });
```

i got an error like below.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'Domain.Campaign.CampaignWorkType'

how i can solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can return an anonymous type.

Comment: If your tables have so many columns that they cause your query to run noticeably slower, then you should probably refactor your DB tables. Can't you just remove those columns from the designer?

Comment: if u cant understand, please dont give an answer.

Comment: By `new {...}` you're creating a list of anonymous types, not `CampaignWorkType`s. The `possible duplicate` link shows a structural approach.

Comment: @GertArnold
thanks but i have already know what you said,however i fixed my problem....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is:

First, define a surrogate type:

```
public class CampaignWorkTypesSimpleList
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then change generic method like this:

```
public List<U> GetBy<T,U>(DbContext context,Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp, Expression<Func<T,U>> columns) 
                where T : class
                where U : class
{

  return dbContext.Set<T>().Where(exp).Select<T, U>(columns).ToList();
}
```

Finally, execute it.

```
List<CampaignWorkTypesSimpleList> list = this.GetBy<CampaignWorkType, CampaignWorkTypesSimpleList>(dbContext, c => c.Active == true, n => new CampaignWorkTypesSimpleList { Id = n.Id, Name = n.Name });
```

Comment: how do you know which table its querying? [edit] nevermind - it the dbset set by T (written here for other people who might need it)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using the EF designer, remove the [Data] column from the Entity Model using the Entity Model design surface.